# How long a printk command would take ?

Tags: android, linux, kernel

I use printk to output interrupt time-stamps at kernel level, meaning one printk every interrupt (in irg_handler_ method). While using that new kernel, I noticed that my device runs slower. 
 So my question is how long each printk command would take to execute ? 
 Any other lighter command that I can use instead for output/debugging purposes ? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The answer would totally depend on the system and one can only tell by profiling. However, if you're convinced that printk is talking too long and you need to reduce it, you can print to a memory buffer (perhaps a circular log buffer) and have a lazy out-of-band mechanism to print this to console.

Comment: Thanks Skjaidev(what a hard name to type) lol.
Could you give more detail on how to profile printk ? Btw, I am running on samsung galaxy tablet 10.1.